# Random order list of list

Tags: list-manipulation, front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, sorting

I have a dynamic `PopupMenu` defined as follow:

```
var = { PopupMenu[Dynamic[r3], 
   {"",{py,px,tn},{px,py,tn},{-px,-py,tn},{px,py,-tn}}
]}
```

`px,px,tn`are 3 numbers.

How can I random sort the order of the these elements, keeping the first always `""`?

For example, I would like `var` to contain

```
{"",{py,px,tn},{px,py,tn},{-px,-py,tn},{px,py,-tn}}
```

one time, and another time

```
{"",{px,py,tn},{py,px,tn},{px,py,-tn},{-px,-py,tn}}
```

Furthermore, I would like the elements of the `PopupMenu` displayed in the following form: `px,py,tn` and not `{px,py,tn}`

Comment: Look up `RandomSample[]`.

Comment: @Kuba I want to call it in different part of the notebook and "always" have a different result

Comment: Like: `var := {PopupMenu[
   Dynamic[r3], {"", 
    Sequence @@ 
     RandomSample[{{py, px, tn}, {px, py, tn}, {-px, -py, tn}, {px, 
        py, -tn}}]}]}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59499/discussion-between-kuba-and-ale1794).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var := PopupMenu[Dynamic[x],
  Prepend[
       # -> Row[#, ","] & /@ RandomSample[
           {{py, px, tn}, {px, py, tn}, {-px, -py, tn}, {px, py, -tn}} 
       ]
    ,  ""
  ]
]
```

[image]

The code should be self explanatory but feel free to ask if anything is unclear.